# Show that $\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}\left[ x^{n-1}f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I prove that
$$\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}\left[ x^{n-1}f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
without using mathematical induction? For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: assuming that the n-th derivative exists

Comment: Is it mandatory that you avoid induction or is that what you prefer? Because you make it quite difficult for yourself by avoiding induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my first answer was -- admittedly -- not that helpful so here's another one:

1. You can try to prove the result for a smaller class of functions $f$, say analytical functions.
   Because the map $$T : f \mapsto \frac{d^n}{dx^n}[x^{n-1}f(1/x)] - \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}(1/x) $$
   is linear in $f$, we may even try to prove the result for monomials $f(x) = x^N$ first.

   $$ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}[x^{n-1}f(1/x)]
       = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^{n-1-N}
       = (n-1-N)^{\underline{n}}x^{-1-N}
      $$
   Here I used the notation: $a^{\underline{b}}$ is the $b$-th [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Alternate_notations) of $a$.
   Further we have
   $$ \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}(1/x)
       = (-1)^nx^{-(n+1)}\frac{d^n}{ds^n}|_{s=1/x}s^{N}
       = (-1)^nx^{-(n+1)}N^{\underline{n}}x^{-(N-n)}
       = (n-1-N)^{\underline{n}}x^{-1-N}
      $$
   Hence $T(f) = 0$ for monomials $f$.
2. By linearity $T$ also vanishes on polynomials.
3. Without loss we may assume that $f(1/x)$ is defined on a bounded interval $I=[a,1/a]$ for $a\in (0,1)$, so $T : C^{n}(I) \to C^{0}(I)$. $C^{n}(I)$ is equipped with the norm $\|f\|_{C^n} := \max\{\|f\|_\infty, ..., \|f^{(n)}\|_\infty \}$. $C^0(I)$ is equipped with the uniform norm. We need to show that $T$ is continuous.
4. Now it remains to show that the polynomials on $I$ are dense in $C^n(I)$, which has been shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448590/polynomials-dense-in-cka-b) using Jackson's theorem.